# Why encoding is different to system defaults in Maven and how to change this setting?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, encoding, utf-8

I have 2 Java projects, running in Netbeans IDE. The first one is a standart Java application and the other one is a Maven project. After reading some texts with error (Getting ??? instead of some Turkish chars) from JTextFields, I have find out that encoding settings are different between these projects.

When I execute this code

```
System.out.println(String.format("file.encoding: %s", System.getProperty("file.encoding")));
System.out.println(String.format("defaultCharset: %s", Charset.defaultCharset().name()));
```

I get these outputs; for the standart application:

```
file.encoding: UTF-8
defaultCharset: UTF-8
```

which is correct but for the Maven project:

```
file.encoding: Cp1252
defaultCharset: windows-1252
```

I don't understand, in my pom.xml encoding attributes are UTF-8.

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
...
```

I did not modify any other settings, I don't know where this property is being overridden. I have seached the Internet and tried adding some plugin dependencies (with encoding property set to "utf-8") to pom.xml but this didn't work and I removed all those extra rows from pom.xml.

Why Maven would alter default encoding and where we can set this property to system defaults?

Comment: How do you run the maven project?

Comment: @assylias Debugging my code in Netbeans on a Win10 machine.

Comment: Probably netbeans settings then - you sohuld be able to pass a `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` parameter to the netbeans JVM.

Comment: @assylias Yes, this works but why we have to do this if our project is a Maven project?

Comment: If you select your Maven project in the **Projects** panel, right-click and select **Properties...** from the context menu, and then select *Sources* from the **Categories** list, what is shown in the *Encoding* field?

Comment: @skomisa "UTF-8"as it is supposed to be, quite weird isn't it?